# Lightroom: how to import GPS location when adding DNG after JPG?

Tags: lightroom, jpeg, geotagging, dng

I do have the following problem:

I imported many pics as JPG files, which contain GPS metadata and created collections etc. Now I added the corresponding DNG files so that Lightroom merges them. The DNG files contain no GPS metadata and thus now the GPS metadata is gone in the merged file which shows up in Lightroom.

How can I tell Lightroom 6 to use the GPS metadata from the corresponding JPG files without reimporting everything, which would require sorting the pics into the collections again?

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure how to do this in Lightroom, or if you even can, but I have an alternate solution: remove the DNGs from Lightroom, then use Exiftool too copy the GPS tags from the JPEG files to the DNG files, and then re-import.

If I understand the situation correctly, this won't undo your organization, since you can leave the JPEGs as placeholders for the sorting.

To do this with ExifTool, assuming you have files named `*.JPG` and `*.RAW` in the same directory (in the example, the current directory, `.`):

```
exiftool -tagsfromfile %d%f.JPG  -gps:all -r -ext RAW .
```

This will leave a bunch of backup files — if you're sure, you can add `-overwrite_original` to avoid that.